# Without loops, how to check if two arrays are equal or not?

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I have two equal-dim arrays in VBScript and I would like to check if they contain the exact values. If they differ in only one value, then they are not equal.

I don't care about the values themselves. And I need to do it WITHOUT loops. I mean something similar to `if arrx() = arry() then`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edited** to adapt to comments.

Maybe this could (depending on real data) do the trick

```
If Join(arrx, Chr(0)) = Join(arry, Chr(0)) Then
```

Comment: This is good but you probably would want to use a delimiter, otherwise Array(1, 2, 3) would compare equal to Array(12, 3)

Answer (score 1):

To tweak what MC's already provided, I'd use:

```
If Join(arrx,"©©©") = Join(arry,"©©©") Then 
   Something
End If
```

... this would prevent ["this", "one"] from accidentally matching ["thisone"]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Initially i discarded the delimiter thinking it could be found inside the data (in your case `["###",""] = ["", "###"]`), but yes, it is better to use the delimiter.

Comment: I understand... I went for repeated, rarely used characters to reduce the likelihood of false matches. I'm sure there are better (more rarely used) characters, but I do think it's important to use something, repeated, in a way that normal responses would not appear. maybe © would be better.