# How to check if two ranges value is equal

Tags: excel, vba, range, equals

I want to merge cells in columns, if there is the same value in whole row.
  Eg. If A1:G1 range is the same as A2:G2 I want to merge A1:A2 cells, B1:B2 to G1:G2.
With my code below I get run time error 13: type mismatch. I'm assuming, that problem is with checking equality of two ranges.

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, row as Long
row = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).row
For i = row To 7 Step -1
        If Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i, 24)).Value = Range(Cells(i - 1, 7), Cells(i - 1, 24)).Value Then
        For j = 7 To 24 Step 1
            Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(i - 1, j)).Merge
        Next j
        End If
Next i
```

The question is, how to check if both ranges values are equal?

Edit after comments:
With the code below it actually works

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, row As Long
row = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).row
For i = row To 7 Step -1
        If Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i, 24)))), Chr(0)) = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(i - 1, 7), Cells(i - 1, 24)))), Chr(0)) Then
        For j = 7 To 24 Step 1
            Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(i - 1, j)).Merge
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Next j
        End If
Next i
```

However, I'm wondering, why you(@Pᴇʜ) separeted the function for first and last rows.

Also, with my code, without merging cells I had te loop for change cell color:

```
Dim row As Long
row = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).ro
Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(row, 3))
     If row Mod 2 <> 0 Then
       Range(Cells(row, 3), Cells(row, 24)).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 225, 242)
     Else
       Range(Cells(row, 3), Cells(row, 24)).Interior.Color = xlNone
     End If
     row = row + 1
Loop
```

How to deal with that after cells are merged?

Comment: You are dealing with a compiler error, not a runtime one. I think you are taking the value of a whole range, while you can only take the value of a single cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that …

```
Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i, 24)).Value
```

returns an array of values, but you cannot compare an array of values with `=`. Therefore you need to loop throug all these values and compare each value with the corresponding value in

```
Range(Cells(i - 1, 7), Cells(i - 1, 24)).Value
```

Since you already have this loop just move your `If` statement to check this into the loop:

```
Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long, LastRow as Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).row
For iRow = LastRow To 7 Step -1
    For iCol = 7 To 24 Step 1
        If Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = Cells(iRow - 1, iCol).Value Then
            Range(Cells(iRow, iCol), Cells(iRow - 1, iCol)).Merge
        End If
    Next iCol 
Next iRow
```

Note that I changed the variable naming to more meaningful names. This also avoids using `Row` as variable name which is alerady used by Excel itself.

---

Edit according comments

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim RangeToMerge As Range
    Set RangeToMerge = Range("C5:F14")

    Dim FirstMergeRow As Long
    FirstMergeRow = 1

    Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long
    For iRow = 1 To RangeToMerge.Rows.Count - 1
        If Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(RangeToMerge.Rows(FirstMergeRow).Value)), "|") <> _
           Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(RangeToMerge.Rows(iRow + 1).Value)), "|") Then
            If iRow <> FirstMergeRow Then
                For iCol = 1 To RangeToMerge.Columns.Count
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    RangeToMerge.Cells(FirstMergeRow, iCol).Resize(rowsize:=iRow - FirstMergeRow + 1).Merge
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                Next iCol
            End If
            FirstMergeRow = iRow + 1
        End If
    Next iRow

    'merge last ones
    If iRow <> FirstMergeRow Then
        For iCol = 1 To RangeToMerge.Columns.Count
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            RangeToMerge.Cells(FirstMergeRow, iCol).Resize(rowsize:=iRow - FirstMergeRow + 1).Merge
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Next iCol
    End If
End Sub
```

Will turn the following

[image]

into

[image]

Comment: I see. I want to merge cells in columns IF whole ranges are equal so it's better to do that with join I think. However, with new code below, I get run time 1004 application-defined or object-defined error.             
`If Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i, 24)))), Chr(0)) = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(i - 1, 7), Cells(i - 1, 24)))), Chr(0)) Then`

Comment: So you want to merge a column eg A1:A10 if the A1:10 is all the same?

Comment: If A1:G1 range is the same as A2:G2 I want to merge A1:A2 cells, B1:B2 to G1:G2.

Comment: @FilipFrątczak That's a way more complicated. See my edited answer.

Comment: @FilipFrątczak Well that's not how it works to ask questions here. You cannot change your question to something new. I can only answer your original question here, if you got a new quesition then you need to ask a new one. • I separated the merge for the last row because otherwise the won't be detected in the end. My code does not look for rows *not* changeing but for when rows change, to merge everything before the change at once. That means if there is no change in the last row they would remain un-merged without the extre merge.

Comment: Try to do the coloring in the same loop as the merging. If you get stuck or errors ask a new question.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your time. Also, which method will be more efficient? The one you created or mine?

Comment: @FilipFrątczak You need to test it on your data. Mine will only merge once if eg 5 rows are the same. Yours will merge multiple times which could either be slower or cause errors (didn't test it).

Answer (score 1):

The `value` property of a range returns an array if the range has more than one cell.  You can either compare the values of each element in a loop, or you can use `join()` to convert the arrays to strings and then compare those (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167156/without-loops-how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-or-not)).