# VBA formatting table with merged cells

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I've got a function which merges cells in table if whole range has the same value (eg. if A1:G1 is equal to A2:B2 it will merge cells like A1&A2, B1&B2 etc. More here: [How to check if two ranges value is equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55237775/how-to-check-if-two-ranges-value-is-equal))
Now I would like, to change color on table created by that funcion, like first row (doesn't matter if merged or no) filled with color, second blank etc. but I have no idea whether I should color it with merging function or create another which will detect new table with merged rows as one etc. Below is my code:

```
Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, row As Long
    row = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
    k = 1
    For i = 1 To row Step 1
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then Exit For
        If Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)))), Chr(0)) <> Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 3)))), Chr(0)) Then
          If i <> k Then
            For j = 1 To 3 Step 1
                  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                  Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(k, j)).Merge
                  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Next j
          End If
        k = i + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some time I've figured it out by myself. Below is the code:

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, c As Integer
row = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
k = 7
c = 1
For i = 7 To row Step 1
    If Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)))), Chr(0)) <> Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 3)))), Chr(0)) Then
      If i <> k Then
        For j = 1 To 3 Step 1
              Application.DisplayAlerts = False
              Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(k, j)).Merge
              Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Next j
      End If
    Select Case c
        Case 0
            Range(Cells(k, 1), Cells(k, 3)).Interior.Color = xlNone
            c = 1
        Case 1
            For l = 0 To i - k Step 1
                Range(Cells(k + l, 1), Cells(k + l, 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 225, 242)
            Next l
            c = 0
    End Select
    k = i + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test1()

    Dim LastColumn As Long, LastRow As Long, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For i = 2 To LastRow Step 2
            .Range(Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, LastColumn)).Interior.Color = vbGreen '<- You could change the color
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

**Edited Solution:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test1()

    Dim rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set rng = .UsedRange

        .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
        .ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight3"

    End With

End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Edited solution unmerges cells. Still not that.